# Can you create a Python native namespace package where you have code modules directly below the namespace?

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I have some python modules that I currently have packaged from one directory tree, which looks like:

```
toplevel/
  setup.cfg
  setup.py
  toplevel/
    __init_.py
    a.py
    b.py
    c.py
    ...
```

and these get imported by something that looks like

```
import toplevel.a
```

Because a.py ,b.py, and c.py have very different dependencies, I'd like to change this so that they are in separate packages with separate dependencies.

I've tried to do this using native namespace packages, but all the examples in the docs I have seen seem to result in a package where the modules are a sublevel lower, so that the imports look like

import toplevel.a.a

I've gotten that to work, but that isn't what I want. Can what I want be done with native namespace packages?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this isn't possible (I look forward to being corrected if it is).

However, there is a workaround that seems to work for me. If you have native namespace packaging working for imports of the form

`import toplevel.a.a`

with each separate package tree like

```
   pyproject.toml
   setup.cfg
   src\
     toplevel\
       a\
       __init__.py
       a.py
```

then instead of having an empty `__init.py__` at the leaf level, you can instead have one that contains

`from .a import *`

which then will load all the names from a.py into the toplevel.a namespace, at which point they are accessible via

`import toplevel.a`

I found https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-init-for-me-d70a312da583 helpful in thinking about this.